# Unable to print BSON object from javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, find, bson

My mongoDB collection looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5070310e0f3350482b00011d"),
    "emails" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5070310e0f3350482b000120"),
                    "_type" : "Email",
                    "name" : "work",
                    "email" : "peter.loescher@siemens.com",
                    "current" : true
            }
    ]
}
```

and this is the `.js` code i use to print the contents :

```
c = db.contacts.findOne( { "emails.email" : { $ne : null } }, { "emails" : 1 } )

print(c._id.toString() + " " + c.emails[0]);
```

when I try to run this javascript file, it is just displaying the id but not the email array.

```
output:
5070310e0f3350482b00011d [object bson_object]
```

but when I try `c.emails[0].email` is is giving proper result. i.e. `peter.loescher@siemens.com`

All I need is I want to display the whole emails embedded object.

```
i.e.
"emails" : [
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5070310e0f3350482b000120"),
                "_type" : "Email",
                "name" : "work",
                "email" : "peter.loescher@siemens.com",
                "current" : true
        }
]
```

Where I am going wrong?. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need `printjson` to output a nicely formatted JSON:

```
printjson(c.emails[0]);
```

Here it is [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell#Scriptingtheshell-Printing).

Comment: What if I want compact form, not wish it to print multiple lines ?

Comment: @LewisChan please ask another question and describe your requirements